# Test constructor calling a method with Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I'd like to ensure that the constructor is calling a method when instantiated with Sinon, however, I can't seem to get this to work, as I believe the sinon is not watching the correct instantiation:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.someFunction();
  }

  someFunction() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

... and the test

```
describe('constructor', () => {

  it('should call someFunction()', () => {
    const spyFunc = new Spy(new Test(), 'someFunction');
    expect(spyFunc.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to spy to `Test.prototype.someFunction` before invoking constructor.
Something like this

```
sinon.spy(Test.prototype, 'someFunction')
const spyFunc = new Test();
expect(spyFunc.someFunction.calledOnce).to.be.true;
```

Comment: That makes sense... I should've thought about that.